# I am new to react and i am trying bootstrap with react but i am getting this error?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

> .footer {
>   |     position: absolute;
>   |     left: 0;

Answer (score 1):

How are you building your bundle?

If you are using `webpack` the you need to css-loader for css file.